# Pyparsing using Forward to parse recursive expressions

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to recursively parse an expression. I followed a few tutorials, and it seems like Forward() is the class that I need. However, something seemingly simple is causing me trouble.

Here is the code I wrote

```
from pyparsing import *
exp = Forward()
integer = Word(nums)
exp << (integer | (exp + '+' + exp))
input = "1+1"
print exp.parseString(input)
```

I want it to return `['1','+','1']` but it only returns `['1']`

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues you have here. In ascending order of importance:

1. parseString will not raise an exception if there is extra text after the parsed content. Use `exp.parseString(input, parseAll=True)`
2. '|' is MatchFirst, not MatchLongest. Since your integer is first, it will be matched first. Then the parser fails on the '+' all by itself. If you want match longest, use '^' operator.
3. The Biggie: once you convert to '^' (or reorder the expressions to put `exp + exp` first, ahead of integer), you will find yourself blowing up the maximum recursion depth. That is because this parser has left-recursive definition of `exp`. That is, to parse an `exp`, it has to parse an `exp`, for which it has to parse an `exp`, etc. In general, many published BNFs use recursion to describe this kind of repetitive structure, but pyparsing does not do the necessary lookahead/backtrack for that to work. Try `exp <<= integer + ZeroOrMore('+' + integer) | '(' + exp + ')'`  - this expression is *not* left-recursive, since you have to get past an opening parenthesis before parsing a nested `exp`.

EDIT: 
Sorry, I was a little too quick on my earlier suggestion, here is the proper way to do your recursive expression parsing:

```
from pyparsing import *

exp = Forward()
LPAR, RPAR = map(Suppress, "()")
integer = Word(nums)
term = integer | Group(LPAR + exp + RPAR)
exp << term + ZeroOrMore('+' + term)

input = "(1+1) + 1"
print(exp.parseString(input))
```

prints

```
[['1', '+', '1'], '+', '1']
```

If you trace through the code, you'll see the recursion: `exp` is defined using `term`, and `term` is defined using `exp`. The `fourFn.py` example is closest to this style; since writing that, I've added the `infixNotation` method to pyparsing, which would allow you to write:

```
exp = infixNotation(integer, [
                    ('+', 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                    ])
```

`infixNotation` takes care of the recursive definitions internally, implicitly defines the `'(' + exp + ')'` expression, and makes it easy to implement a system of operators with precedence of operations.

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand how it all works. i thought `|` means `or`.

Also, `exp <<= integer + ZeroOrMore('+' + integer) | '(' + exp + ')'` fails on cases like `(1+1)+1`

Comment: Also I need it to be recursive. For example. 

`exp << Integer | exp + '+' + exp`

Answer (score 1):

I recently came to this problem. Now the left recursion is supported on PyParsing 3.0.0b2 or later. But the feature should be explicitly enabled, and the order of operands of the `|` operator should be adjusted like this.

```
from pyparsing import ParserElement, Forward, Word, nums

ParserElement.enable_left_recursion()
exp = Forward()
integer = Word(nums)
exp << ((exp + '+' + exp) | integer)
input = "1+1"
print(exp.parseString(input))
```

This will output the following.

```
['1', '+', '1']
```